# remove append strings

Tags: ios

I have an nsarray with strings like this,

```
albumname/song42.mp3
albumname/song43.mp3 etc .
```

I want to remove the string "album name" and ".mp3" from the above array,and display it in a tableview as follows ,

```
song42
song43
```

then in the DidSelectRow ,i want to add the string 
"http://www.domain.com/albumname/" and ".mp3" to the indepath.row element . 
fo eg :
if user selects song42 in tableview ,then it must create a string like this "http://www.domain.com/albumname/song42.mp3"
How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lastPathComponent` and `stringByDeletingPathExtension` methods:

```
NSMutableArray *songs = [NSArray arrayWithCapacity:[sourceArray count]];
for (NSString *filename in sourceArray) {
    [songs addObject:[[filename lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

[- [NSString stringByDeletingPathExtension]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByDeletingPathExtension) <--- This to remove

[+ [NSString stringWithFormat:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:) <--- And this to recreate

**EDIT** My mistake, you first need to do this before you call the first method:

```
NSString *lastPath = [string lastPathComponent]; //song43.mp3
NSString *tableString = [lastPath stringByDeletingPathExtension]; //song43
```

Comment: That won't work as is - you need to combine it with `lastPathComponent`. For example, given the input `albumname/song42.mp3` if you call `stringByDeletingPathExtension` you'll get `albumname/song42` as the output.

Comment: wait a minute. Does this remove the string,extensions etc  from an array? your above code works for an individual string , isn't it?

Comment: Yes...so loop it over the array, obviously ><;

Answer (score 2):

use the String method `componentsSeparatedByString` first separate the strings using `/` and then `.` and discard what you don't need.

```
NSString *str="albumname/song42.mp3";
NSArray *mainStrArray = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]; 


NSArray remainingStrArray=[[mainStrArray objectAtIndex:1]componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

NSString *result=[remainingStrArray objectAtIndex:0]; //here you have song42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, as :

```
NSString *str = @"album name/song43.mp3";

str=[[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"][1]componentsSeparatedByString:@".mp3"][0];

NSLog(@"->%@",str); //song43
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *file = @"albumname/song42.mp3";
NSString *name = [[[[file componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
```